# R encoding in mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: r, macos, encoding

I'm a new user of Mac OS X, I followed the steps in https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ for installing R 3.2.4, previously I installed XQuartz as recommended.

When I look for the info about the locals it seems to be OK

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I can print words with accents

```
> print("Benito Juárez")
[1] "Benito Juárez"
```

But when I read a table with `read.csv()` and try to make a summary, it does not show the accents (it shows them like in latin1).

```
> base<-read.csv("large_data.csv")
> summary(base$NOM_MUN)
  \xc1lvaro Obreg\xf3n           Azcapotzalco       Benito Ju\xe1rez 
                 28284                  11983                  15067 
           Coyoac\xe1n  Cuajimalpa de Morelos          Cuauht\xe9moc 
                 19934                  12372                  29804 
     Gustavo A. Madero              Iztacalco             Iztapalapa 
                 38822                  15493                  61533 
La Magdalena Contreras         Miguel Hidalgo             Milpa Alta 
                  7676                  16450                   5382 
            Tl\xe1huac                Tlalpan    Venustiano Carranza 
                 15600                  30258                  21200 
            Xochimilco 
                 23172
```

I've tried using `encoding="UTF-8"` in the read.cv function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What form are they in in your data.frame? A little sample table works ok for me, so it's probably an upstream issue. If necessary, `stringi` has some nice utilities for working with accent formats.

Comment: what do you mean with form? the class of the NOM_MUN variable is factor. I also tried with with the data in `DBF` format and using `foreign` package but it did the same thing.

Comment: even using the `enc2utf8` function I can't get the accents `> enc2utf8(base$NOM_MUN[280000])
[1] "Benito Ju\xe1rez"`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly what is doing the conversion. I don't think it's `summary`, so you need to check if the accents are in the right place in the data.frame you're calling `table` upon. You should also check in the .csv, so you know what function you're trying to get to work. Better to avoid the conversion in the first place (if it's happening) than bother with working backwards.